# Git warning: unable to access '/home/user/.gitconfig': Is a directory

Tags: git

I am getting this error for every git command I try to run and haven't found anywhere something similar. I have found stuff like "permission denied" and other problems to access the git configurations but nothing related to this "Is a directory" warning. I don't even know if it is related to the fatal error I am getting, but it is all the information I currently have.

```
user@computer:~/folder$ git status
warning: unable to access '/home/user/.gitconfig': Is a directory
warning: unable to access '/home/user/.gitconfig': Is a directory
fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
```

Comment: Could be a stupid question, but **is** `'/home/user/.gitconfig'` a directory?

Comment: It is. I don't know if it should be or not :/

Comment: No, it should be a file. Question is of course, how did it become a directory...

Comment: Rename the folder and create an empty file called `.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.gitconfig` is a global configuration file of `git` tool.
Like this, your name, email, some tools... https://gist.github.com/gokure/3488458

Not sure how you created your `.gitconfig` directory, but to be safe, rename it to `.gitconfig_backup_dir`, then `git` should then run flawlessly, cause git will not find `$HOME/.gitconfig` but will work without it flawlessly.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar issue, because as the error says the ~/.gitconfig was a directory instead of being a file!

Junji's answer worked for me by renaming the directory but I faced the same error whenever I used git config --global command again as it was making another .gitconfig directory again. To solve this issue permanently, I removed the directory and made a file with the same name and it solved the issue forever as git config --global and other commands which need .gitconfig file could use this file.

I simply deleted the directory with:

```
rmdir ~/.gitconfig
```

and then made a blank new file with the same name:

```
nano ~/.gitconfig
```

That's it. Done!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on WSL2:

1. I could delete this folder from Windows, by going to *\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home<my_username>* and deleting *.gitconfig* folder, but it was immediately recreated.
2. Turns out that what was keeping it busy is the Docker integration for WSL2.
   I stopped the (Windows) process, and I was able to `rm -R ~/.gitconfig` folder from windows.

I then created the file ~/.gitconfig to prevent Docker from repeating this nasty behavior

Answer (score -2):

2020 update: you are going to have to add your username and email to the file